# msbuild conditional target execution multiple projects

Tags: msbuild

This is what I am trying:
For each project in the solution

1. Download the internal.xml file from the server
2. Run xslt using internal.xml as an xslt variable

When I build a single project I don't have a problem. However, when I build the multiple projects in the solution where there are dependencies, I would like to put a check that if internal.xml is already downloaded, don't download it again.

If I don't do this, I get error with multiple projects trying to download and use the internal.xml file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could share a common target among the projects to download the file, and if all the projects share the file from the same location you could do something like:

```
<Target Name="DownloadXmlFile" Condition="!Exists('$(ShareXmlFileDirectory)\internal.xml')">
....
</Target>
```